# Gmail Signature Settings

Tags: api, gmail, settings, signature

I am really new to this website. I hope someone could help me out with an issue that I that am facing now.

I needed to create a mobile app in android which changes gmail signature. I did a bit of googling and end up with this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/

I used the ClientLogin authentication mode (https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin) and got the authorization token. But am unable to proceed further. What I wanted is simply an html code as my gmail signature. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with some sample code or document (any authorization mode will do, I don't really want to stick on with ClientLogin, oAuth will do it for me).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been patiently waiting. Please guys, if someone can comment on this issue. it would be a great help.

Comment: did you get this done? If not you can use java sdk (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)

Comment: Not yet @Venu. I just downloaded the sample from gdata-sample list. But I can't find an example demonstrating gmail-signature settings API. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old(ish) post I know - but had the same issue and solved it this way:

1. Grab yourself a REST client - look at the "Advanced REST Client" by  Paweł Psztyć available on the Google Chrome web-store. Once you have opened the app:

To obtain a new token, follow these steps:

- URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin (deprecated now, but still working)
- Metod: POST
- Headers: Raw Input - 
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body: Form - ad a row for each name and value pair 
       - Email / Google email address 
       - Passwd / user above's password 
       - accountType / HOSTED (if hosted) 
       - service / apps

Hit send and you will receive the SID, LSID and Auth. Grab the Auth only and change the params in your REST client:

- URL: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain name}/{username}/signature
- Metod: PUT
- Headers: Raw Input 
          Content-type: application/atom+xml
          Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=your-authentication-token-received-above
- Body: Raw Input

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
    <apps:property name="signature" value="Liz Jones - (+1) 619-555-5555
Accounts Management, A&amp;Z LTD." />
    </atom:entry>`

(info as per here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings)

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fraccus. But, what I was asking was how can I get this done from android application code. From your answer I can see, I get these tokens with the help of another application, and so I can use it in the email settings service, which might not be possible in my case. For me, the user has to enter his account credentials (or any other authentication mechanishm) and by doing that he/she should be able to log-in. Now with that token, use email-setting service. Hope you got my point.

Comment: you can still follow the steps I mentioned. Just add all the relevant fields to your POST url. Format of the URL here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#formingtheurl

The REST client helps you to visually debug what you're doing, but the principle remains. You call a URL (with the user's info), on redirect you can set the signature settings.

Comment: I know this is an old post but just wanted to note this no longer seems to work. You now need a 'service account' and OAuth2 if I understand it correctly.